# recyclerview doesn't show any thing in fragment

Tags: android, json, android-recyclerview, android-volley, android-glide

hi guys i have a card view that populate it's data from a json. I parse json with volley and it is successfull .
but in card view there is nothing to show

here is my json

```
{"photo":[{"id":"4","profile_id":"mahdi","caption":"hello","image_url":"https:\/\/hemispheric-suggest.000webhostapp.com\/img\/img\/birjand.jpg","profile_img_url":"https:\/\/hemispheric-suggest.000webhostapp.com\/prof\/prof\/prof_1.jpg","insert_time":"2017-07-09 11:21:44"}
```

and my fragment adapter :

```
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
ArrayList<Card> list = new ArrayList<>();

String url = "My url";
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag,container,false);
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycler);

    mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());

    list();

    LinearLayoutManager MyLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    MyLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(new Adapter(list));
    return view;
}


public class Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter.MyviewHolder>{

   // private ArrayList<Card> list;

    public Adapter(ArrayList<Card> data) {
        list = data;
    }

    public class MyviewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        public TextView textView;
        public ImageView imageView;
        public MyviewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            textView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
            imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public MyviewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_row,parent,false);
        return new MyviewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyviewHolder holder, int position) {

        Card card = list.get(position);
        holder.textView.setText(card.getName());
        Glide.with(getActivity()).load(card.getImg()).into(holder.imageView);

    }



    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return list.size();
    }
}

public void list() {

    JsonObjectRequest object = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    try{

                        JSONArray array = response.getJSONArray("photo");
                        for (int i = 0; i <array.length() ; i++) {
                            JSONObject temp = array.getJSONObject(i);
                            Card card = new Card();
                            card.setName(temp.getString("profile_id"));
                            card.setImg(temp.getString("image_url"));
                            list.add(card);
                        }


                    }catch (Exception ex){
                    }
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                }
            }
    );
    mRequestQueue.add(object);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Volley is asynchronus, so when you call:

```
recyclerView.setAdapter(new Adapter(list));
```

just a few milliseconds after you enqueued your request, It's very likely that the list is still empty because Volley hasn't received any response yet. You should set your adapter once you get the response inside the onResponse callback.